# Parsing parameters from NSArray to NSString

Tags: objective-c

Here i uploaded my response like:

```
<__NSCFArray 0x7fc27364d270>(
{
    Emailid = "mannam1@gmail.com";
    MobileNo = 946545364;
    Name = Brahmam;
    Password = 1234;
    id = 120;
}
)
```

I wrote code like this::

```
userIdStr = [array1 valueForKey:@"id"];
userEmailIdStr = [array1 valueForKey:@"Emailid"];
userPasswordStr = [array1 valueForKey:@"Password"];
userFirstNameStr = [array1 valueForKey:@"Name"];
userMobileNoStr = [array1 valueForKey:@"MobileNo"];
```

But I am not getting proper response in `String`. How can I get? Can you please help me out?

Comment: how exactly do the strings look then?

Comment: I am getting response like::: <__NSArrayI 0x7f914acf67c0>(
120
)

but i am looking for ::     120

Comment: So, your array contains 1 dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Fetch as below,

```
userIdStr = [[array1 objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"id"];
userEmailIdStr = [[array1 objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"Emailid"];
userPasswordStr = [[array1 objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"Password"];
userFirstNameStr = [[array1 objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"Name"];
userMobileNoStr = [[array1 objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"MobileNo"];
```

Comment: ThanQ. It's perfect solution for me

Answer (score 1):

That's the famous `valueForKey:` trap.

`valueForKey:` is a KVC method with a special functionality.
Applied on an array of dictionaries it returns always an array containing all values for the specific key.

To get a single value for a key use **always** `objectForKey:` or subscripting.

```
userIdStr = [array1[0] objectForKey:@"id"];

or

userIdStr = array1[0][@"id"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should understand JSON first. For your case, it returns an array that has one element. That element is another JSON structure. Also, you will also need to know the purpose of `valueForKey`. It simply accesses the **property** from `NSArray` by string which is meaningless for library classes. That's widely used when you create your own class for setting or getting the **property** by using string.

What you need to do is: fetch that element as `NSDictionary`, that's the data structure you want. Then, you can use the simple pattern to retrieve the value from key.